# Invariant Violation: React only expected single element (When changing Modal visible from false to true)

Tags: react-native, expo

When changing the modal visible prop from false to true, I get an Invariant Violation error.  Everything used to work perfectly fine.  I think that one of the recent releases from Expo or React Native broke it.  I haven't changed the code in months and it was working for the past 6-9 months.  I'm just not sure how recent the problem is.

I tried setting state using a function.  I changed the modal visible to "true" without using a state variable and I still get the same error.

```
// function to change the modal state
setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
}

// Button to show the modal
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.dateEdit} onPress={() => {this.setModalVisible(true);}}>
    <Icon name="ios-calendar" style={styles.bold} />
    <Text style={styles.editText}>Edit</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

<Modal animationType="slide" visible={this.state.modalVisible} transparent={true}>
          <View style={{height: "100%"}}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{height: '60%'}} onPress={() => {this.setState({modalVisible: false})}}>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          <View  style={styles.dateModal}>
            <DatePickerIOS date={this.state.chosenDate} onDateChange={this.setDate} mode={'date'} />
                <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.modalBtn}
                    onPress={() => {
                      this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                    }}>
                    <Text style={styles.modalBtnText}>Save Date</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
            </Modal>
```

When I click the button, I expect the modal to show up.  instead I get an error.

> The whole error reads: "Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TouchableWithoutFeedback` expects child to be passed, otherwise it will crash

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => {this.setState({modalVisible: false})}}
>
    <View style={{ height: 30, width: 50, borderWidth: 1}} />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: That was the problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like the error states, React components expects to receive a single React element child. So you need to wrap in span or any other valid React JSX element:

```
<React.Fragment>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.dateEdit} onPress={() => { this.setModalVisible(true); }}>
        <Icon name="ios-calendar" style={styles.bold} />
        <Text style={styles.editText}>Edit</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Modal animationType="slide" visible={this.state.modalVisible} transparent={true}>
        <View style={{ height: "100%" }}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{ height: '60%' }} onPress={() => { this.setState({ modalVisible: false }) }}>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <View style={styles.dateModal}>
                <DatePickerIOS date={this.state.chosenDate} onDateChange={this.setDate} mode={'date'} />
                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.modalBtn}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                        }}>
                        <Text style={styles.modalBtnText}>Save Date</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    </Modal>
</React.Fragment>
```